# VPN asks for username and password only for network drive access

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, vpn

I have a weird problem I hope someone can shed some light on. I have a user who uses a Windows 7 laptop at home. The machine is on our domain and he can access the VPN with no problem, and intranet/email access isn't a problem either. However, when he tries to access network drives mapped to his account he's denied access. He's prompted for a user name and password every time. I've tested the machine out with one of our hotspot devices and it seems to work fine here. My guess is that it could be a home network issue, but I'm not sure what would cause this. Is there anything we can look for as far as home networking equipment that would block access to drives like this?

Comment: Does this happen when his W7 machine is directly connected to the domain?

Comment: No, it does not. When we have the machine linked up to VPN using one of our hotspots we can't reproduce the problem either. It seems to only happen at the user's house. That's what's go me scratching my head.

Comment: It has got me scratching too! It looks like a problem with the W7 settings, but I've upgraded all my W7 systems to W10, so I can't do meaningful tests. I can't see what home network settings could affect this. Is there only one user experiencing this, or are there others using VPN who are unaffected?

Comment: It's just the one user. He's able to access those same network drives here at the office, it just seems to be when he's at home, and the intranet sites work while he's on VPN. I was thinking it could be a win 7 setting too, but I'm not sure what settings I should check. We've tried his credentials using other hotspots and they seems to work then.

Comment: I've also tried using a different machine, but he has the same issue. That's why I'm leaning more toward a home network issue, but even then I don't know what would cause that.

Comment: If you could try his machine on a different remote network, that might help to isolate the problem between network set-up and W7 settings.

Comment: I'm wondering if he's not actually connecting to the intended server when trying to access the mapped drive from home.... What is the IP address of the server hosting the mapped drive?  Can you post a screen shot of `ipconfig /all` run from the user's machine at home while connected to the VPN?

Comment: I'll try to see if I can get a screenshot later tonight when he's accessing the system again.